# Why is path with more root slashes valid?

Tags: linux, filesystems, path

In linux system, if you change directory into '//' you can browse the file system, while your root will be '//'. This does not happen with more slashes, more slashes produce original '/'.

Possible working directories:

```
[user@host /]$ cd //
[user@host //]$ pwd # Results in double root
//
[user@host //]$ cd srv/ftp
[user@host ftp]$ pwd # Double root is preserved but no other effects observed
//srv/ftp
[user@host /]$ cd ////
[user@host /]$ cd ///////
[user@host /]$ cd ////////// # Additional slashes change nothing
[user@host /]$
```

Why does this happen? How is it even valid?

(Observed on Linux host 4.18.16-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Oct 20 22:06:45 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Comment: Highly relevant:  [On what systems is //foo/bar different from /foo/bar?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256497/23408)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer after better searching, it turns out:

> Multiple slashes are allowed and are equivalent to a single slash. From the Single Unix specification (version 3), base definitions §3.266 pathname: “Multiple successive slashes are considered to be the same as one slash.”
>
> There is one exception: if a pathname starts with exactly two slashes, it may be treated differently (ref: base definitions §4.11 pathname resolution). Linux itself doesn't do this, though some applications might, and other unix-ish system do (e.g. Cygwin).

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919/276644